# SVG - Mutiple images with different behaviors

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to build a graphic and here's the idea:

I'd have one image representing when the graphic is empty and the othe one when it's filled.

So I'd have one image 100% width and the other 20%, 50% and so on

the problem is I don't know how to specify which image I'd like to change the width property

here's a fiddle with both images 100%, I'd like to change the red one to 80% (for example):

http://jsfiddle.net/q62aw1bk/

code:

```
 <svg height="100%" width="100%">
         <image xlink:href="http://www.cebbra44.com/images/barra_verde.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
         <image xlink:href="http://www.construtorafgs.com.br/img/bgs/barra_porcentagem_vermelha.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <defs>
                 <clipPath id="theSVGPath">
                       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                 </clipPath>
           </defs>
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

ps: I can't simply change one of the image's width, because they must be the same height the clip path must be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the clip path for only one of your images by adding a `class` attribute and altering your CSS to select only that image.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q62aw1bk/1/)

(Clipping the entire SVG to 100% of its width and height was redundant anyway, so instead we'll clip only the image that needs to be clipped.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using simple `rect`s and a gradient instead of the images? Then you could manipulate the width directly without messing around with `clip-path`s.

```html
<svg width="500px" height="100px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="indicator-gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(0, 100%, 38%)"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(0, 100%, 31%)"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="2%" width="96%" height="100%" fill="hsl(78, 66%, 45%)"></rect>
  <rect y="25%" width="20%" height="50%" fill="url(#indicator-gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

(There is also a performance benefit here as rendering the SVG elements is faster than requesting the image resources from the server. The total download size to the client will be smaller, too.)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the graphics are not a simple rectangles (like in my jsfiddle) it's an image :\  so far I just created two svgs  and it's working but it seems kinda ugly to me.

Comment: I see. I'll add another answer that maintains the images.